# The `podspec` specification does not validate

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, frameworks, cocoapods

> ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find other source ref for /private/var/folders/bb/z6vn13c50099chk1ff861s8m0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190627-13964-tnz1yj-Vboard/Pods/Vboard/VboardFramework/Assets.xcassets/30x30.imageset/30x30.png for target Vboard.) during validation. [!] The `Vboard.podspec` specification does not validate.

[image]

This image was in my repository but now i have deleted this image form everywhere, i dont know why this error is appearing. Here is my Podspec code:

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
 # 1
 s.platform = :ios 
s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
 s.name = "Vboard"
 s.summary = "VBoard. is video at your fingertips! Add videos from everywhere to your conversations anywhere."
 s.requires_arc = true s.version = "1.0" 
# 3 
s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" } 
# 4 - Replace with your name and e-mail address 
s.author = { "Rabia" => "rabia.dastgir@argonteq.com" } 
# 5 - Replace this URL with your own GitHub page's URL (from the address bar) 
s.homepage = "https://github.com/ArgonTech/Vboard" 
# 6 - Replace this URL with your own Git URL from "Quick Setup" s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/ArgonTech/Vboard.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" } 
# 7 s.framework = "UIKit" s.dependency 'SDWebIma##
```

##ge', '~>3.7' s.dependency "YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView", "~> 0.2.0" # 8 s.source_files = "VboardFramework/**/*" # 9 s.resources = "VboardFramework/***/.{jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets}" end Please let me know, where i am wrong? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Please fix the formatting, but it looks like the s.source_files line is commented out.

Comment: s.source_files = "VboardFramework/**/*"
s.resources = "VboardFramework/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets}"

Comment: in my code it was not commented, above i have added how i am adding source and resource files, but still issue appears.